# I am trying to write a vba code to extract Data from a workbook based a given date range. User should be able to enter date range

Tags: vba, excel, date

I am trying to write a simple vba code to extract data from the work hour sheet. User should be able to specify a date range and the vba code should able to extract the data based on the range.

The hour sheet has dates mentioned in the columns and work items in the rows. Users put their hour spend for the day against the given work item in the corresponding dates.

For ex. if I select range 01-08-2015 to 01-08-2015 the code should be able to extract the hour spend in the given date range for the particular work item. The data should then be shown to the user in the Calculations sheet.
I was looking to add a command button to facilitate the process

Work Items are arranged in rows and dates are arranged in columns.

Comment: What attached sheet? Have any attempts been made? If so could you post what you have tried doing?

Comment: I tried attaching a sheet but was not able to.

Comment: Okay. Regarding this issue though. Have you tried to make anything? Even if it didn't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing the spreadsheet, my gut would say to try something like this.  Create a new sheet that has a spot for the starting date and ending date to be put in cells, eg A2 = starting date and B2 = ending date.  If this is for a user, have the label for this in A1 and B1.  Add a command button that will run the macro.  macro should use a loop to find all the dates within the range, it would be easiest if the master data sheet was sorted, then have the code copy and paste the cells as needed.  Without more details on the sheet layout, I can't really put some code together for you.